# Propel generates 0 instead of false

Tags: linux, postgresql, propel

I have a problem with my project and propel orm. When I use find() propel generate a query with 0 instead of false and my postgres give me an exception. Example:

...WHERE documento.DOCUMENTO_ELIMINADO=0...

I hope you can help me please. Thanks.

Comment: ... because `documento.DOCUMENTO_ELIMINADO` is a boolean column?'

Answer (score 2):

Did you rebuild your model? The front-page for the Propel ORM suggests that's necessary when you change databases.

In PostgreSQL, comparing a boolean and an integer fails:

```
regress=# SELECT 0 == 'f'::boolean;
ERROR:  operator does not exist: integer == boolean
LINE 1: SELECT 0 == 'f'::boolean;
                 ^
```

so I'm guessing your ORM thinks it's talking to MySQL. Guessing, because you've provided very little information to go on.

Otherwise: More information required. Queries, exact text of error messages, table definitions, etc.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

documento.DOCUMENTO_ELIMINADO is a boolean column and propel generate 0 instead of "false" value.

By another hand, i guess postgres think it is using mysql, but in my conection is specified pgsql driver. May be there is a config file where i would set driver